# Plotting Elevation in Python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, cartopy, python-iris

I'm trying to create a map of Malawi with altitude shown. Something like this, but of Malawi of course:

[image]

I have downloaded some elevation data from here: http://research.jisao.washington.edu/data_sets/elevation/

This is a print of that data after I created a cube:

```
meters, from 5-min data / (unknown) (time: 1; latitude: 360; longitude: 720)
     Dimension coordinates:
          time                           x            -               -
          latitude                       -            x               -
          longitude                      -            -               x
     Attributes:
          history: 
Elevations calculated from the TBASE 5-minute
latitude-longitude resolution...
          invalid_units: meters, from 5-min data
```

I started with importing my data, forming a cube, removing the extra variables (time and history) and limiting my data to the latitudes and longitudes for Malawi.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as mpl_cm
import numpy as np
import iris
import cartopy
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
import iris.analysis.cartography


def main():

    #bring in altitude data
    Elev = '/exports/csce/datastore/geos/users/s0899345/Climate_Modelling/Actual_Data/elev.0.5-deg.nc'

    Elev= iris.load_cube(Elev)

    #remove variable for time
    del Elev.attributes['history']
    Elev = Elev.collapsed('time', iris.analysis.MEAN)

    Malawi = iris.Constraint(longitude=lambda v: 32.0 <= v <= 36., latitude=lambda v: -17. <= v <= -8.)      
    Elev = Elev.extract(Malawi)

    print 'Elevation'
    print Elev.data
    print 'latitude'
    print Elev.coord('latitude')
    print 'longitude'
    print Elev.coord('longitude')
```

This works well and the output is as follows:

```
Elevation
[[  978.  1000.  1408.  1324.  1080.  1370.  1857.  1584.]
 [ 1297.  1193.  1452.  1611.  1354.  1480.  1350.   627.]
 [ 1418.  1490.  1625.  1486.  1977.  1802.  1226.   482.]
 [ 1336.  1326.  1405.   728.  1105.  1559.  1139.   789.]
 [ 1368.  1301.  1463.  1389.   671.   942.   947.   970.]
 [ 1279.  1116.  1323.  1587.   839.  1014.  1071.  1003.]
 [ 1096.   969.  1179.  1246.   855.   979.   927.   638.]
 [  911.   982.  1235.  1324.   681.   813.   814.   707.]
 [  749.   957.  1220.  1198.   613.   688.   832.   858.]
 [  707.  1049.  1037.   907.   624.   771.  1142.  1104.]
 [  836.  1044.  1124.  1120.   682.   711.  1126.   922.]
 [ 1050.  1204.  1199.  1161.   777.   569.   999.   828.]
 [ 1006.   869.  1183.  1230.  1354.   616.   762.   784.]
 [  838.   607.   883.  1181.  1174.   927.   591.   856.]
 [  561.   402.   626.   775.  1053.   726.   828.   733.]
 [  370.   388.   363.   422.   508.   471.   906.  1104.]
 [  504.   326.   298.   208.   246.   160.   458.   682.]
 [  658.   512.   334.   309.   156.   162.   123.   340.]]
latitude
DimCoord(array([ -8.25,  -8.75,  -9.25,  -9.75, -10.25, -10.75, -11.25, -11.75,
       -12.25, -12.75, -13.25, -13.75, -14.25, -14.75, -15.25, -15.75,
       -16.25, -16.75], dtype=float32), standard_name='latitude', units=Unit('degrees'), var_name='lat', attributes={'title': 'Latitude'})
longitude
DimCoord(array([ 32.25,  32.75,  33.25,  33.75,  34.25,  34.75,  35.25,  35.75], dtype=float32), standard_name='longitude', units=Unit('degrees'), var_name='lon', attributes={'title': 'Longitude'})
```

However when I try to plot it, it doesn't work... this is what I did:

```
#plot map with physical features 
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)   
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)
#plot altitude data
plot=ax.plot(Elev, cmap=mpl_cm.get_cmap('YlGn'), levels=np.arange(0,2000,150), extend='both') 
#add colour bar index and a label
plt.colorbar(plot, label='meters above sea level')
#set map boundary
ax.set_extent([32., 36., -8, -17]) 
#set axis tick marks
ax.set_xticks([33, 34, 35]) 
ax.set_yticks([-10, -12, -14, -16]) 
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
#save the image of the graph and include full legend
plt.savefig('Map_data_boundary', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The error I get is `'Attribute Error: Unknown property type cmap'` and the following map of the whole world...

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll prepare the data the same as you, except to remove the `time` dimension I'll use [`iris.util.squeeze`](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/iris/iris/util.html#iris.util.squeeze), which removes any length-1 dimension.

```
import iris

elev = iris.load_cube('elev.0.5-deg.nc')
elev = iris.util.squeeze(elev)
malawi = iris.Constraint(longitude=lambda v: 32.0 <= v <= 36.,
                         latitude=lambda v: -17. <= v <= -8.)      
elev = elev.extract(malawi)
```

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest says, you want a contour plot.  When unsure what plotting function to use, I recommend browsing the matplotlib [gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) to find something that looks similar to what you want to produce.  Click on an image and it shows you the code.

So, to make the contour plot you can use the `matplotlib.pyplot.contourf` function, but you have to get the relevant data from the cube in the form of `numpy` arrays:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as mpl_cm
import numpy as np
import cartopy

cmap = mpl_cm.get_cmap('YlGn')
levels = np.arange(0,2000,150)
extend = 'max'

ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
plt.contourf(elev.coord('longitude').points, elev.coord('latitude').points, 
             elev.data, cmap=cmap, levels=levels, extend=extend)
```

[image: matplotlib.pyplot version]

However, `iris` provides a shortcut to the `maplotlib.pyplot` functions in the form of [`iris.plot`](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/iris/iris/plot.html).  This automatically sets up an axes instance with the right projection, and passes the data from the cube through to `matplotlib.pyplot`.  So the last two lines can simply become:

```
import iris.plot as iplt
iplt.contourf(elev, cmap=cmap, levels=levels, extend=extend)
```

[image: iris.plot version]

There is also [`iris.quickplot`](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/iris/iris/quickplot.html), which is basically the same as `iris.plot`, except that it automatically adds a colorbar and labels where appropriate:

```
import iris.quickplot as qplt
qplt.contourf(elev, cmap=cmap, levels=levels, extend=extend)
```

[image: iris.quickplot version]

Once plotted, you can get hold of the axes instance and add your other items (for which I simply copied your code):

```
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter

qplt.contourf(elev, cmap=cmap, levels=levels, extend=extend)
ax = plt.gca()

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)   
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)

ax.set_xticks([33, 34, 35]) 
ax.set_yticks([-10, -12, -14, -16]) 
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
```

[image: iris.quickplot with additions]

Comment: Thank you @RuthC, this is a very clear and helpful response! Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want something like a contour plot. So instead of

```
plot = ax.plot(...)
```

you probably want to use

```
plot = ax.contourf(...)
```

Most probably you also want to give latitude and longitude as arguments to `contourf`,

```
plot = ax.contourf(longitude, latitude, Elev, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've changed it to `plot=ax.contourf(Elev.coord('latitude'), Elev.coord('longitude'), Elev.data, cmap=YlGn, levels=np.arange(0,2000,150), extend='both')` but now getting the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: Always provide full code and full error traceback. Otherwise it is impossible to know what's happening.

Comment: Apologies, I updated `#plot altitude data
plot=ax.plot(Elev, cmap=mpl_cm.get_cmap('YlGn'), levels=np.arange(0,2000,150), extend='both')` to now read this `#plot altitude data
    YlGn = plt.get_cmap('YlGn')  
    plot=ax.contourf(Elev.coord('latitude'), Elev.coord('longitude'), Elev.data, cmap=YlGn, levels=np.arange(0,2000,150), extend='both')`

Comment: The error: File "/home/s0899345/datastore/Climate_Modelling/Python_Code_and_Output_Images/Map_boundary_altitudes.py", line 51, in main
    plot=ax.contourf(Elev.coord('latitude'), Elev.coord('longitude'), Elev.data, cmap=YlGn, levels=np.arange(0,2000,150), extend='both')
  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 1333, in contourf
    result = matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1819, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: (Con't)   
  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5627, in contourf
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1424, in __init__
    ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 863, in __init__
    self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: (Con't 2)   File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1445, in _process_args
    x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1528, in _contour_args
    x, y, z = self._check_xyz(args[:3], kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1557, in _check_xyz
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float64)

Comment: (Con't 3)   File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: It is not useful to put code or traceback in the comments. In any case it seems you cannot put the DimCoords object into contourf, but instead you need to pass the numpy array directly. I have never worked with Iris, but I would try `Elev.coord('longitude').data`.

Comment: Sorry @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks again but this doesn't work either.You get the error `AttributeError: 'DimCoord' object has no attribute 'data'` As you can see in my original post I have printed the longitude and latitude as `Elev.coord('longitude')` and that works.

Comment: I have tried to predefine them as `Lat = Elev.coord('latitude')`,
    `Lon = Elev.coord('longitude')` and
    `Elev = Elev.data` and then run `plot=ax.contourf(Lat, Lon, Elev, cmap=YlGn, levels=np.arange(0,2000,150), extend='both')` but this still comes back with the original error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: You need to find out how to get the numpy array out of the `DimCoord` object. I cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this:

```
import matplotlib.colors as colors

color = plt.get_cmap('YlGn')  # and change cmap=mpl_cm.get_cmap('YlGn') to  cmap=color
```

And also try to update your matplotlib:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

**EDIT**

```
color = plt.get_cmap('YlGn')  # and change cmap=mpl_cm.get_cmap('YlGn') to  cmap=color
```

Comment: Thanks Vasily, Appreciate your help, but that didnt work :( No change.

Comment: you can try to find something [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Comment: Thanks Vasily, I've looked there already, but no luck. It's strange as I used the same coding on a different dataset and it works perfectly. I didnt need to import anything in particular and cmap is understood. I just can't get it to run with this data....